# jQuery event handlers not toggling CSS Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button on my site called "Login" and when this button is clicked a dropdown box appears allowing users to enter their details. The dropdown is handled in a jQuery Script however it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
 <div class="header-login">
        <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Login</a>
        <div>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">Forgot Password?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 var $headerLoginRegister = $('#header .header-login, #header .headerregister');

$headerLoginRegister.each(function () {
 var $this = $(this);

 $this.children('a').on('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $this.toggleClass('active');
 });

 $this.on('clickoutside touchendoutside', function () {
     if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
         $this.removeClass('active');
     }
 });

 });



var $headerNavbar = $('#header .header-nav-bar .primary-nav > li');

  $headerNavbar.each(function () {
var $this = $(this);

$this.children('a').on('click', function (event) {
  $this.toggleClass('active');
});

$this.on('clickoutside touchendoutside', function () {
  if ($this.hasClass('active')) { $this.removeClass('active'); }
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6k9ptg06/ - Here is the exact code I have on my site, when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: First provide your complete `HTML` . Also you selector as specified in the question is `$('#header .header-login, #header .headerregister');` and I do not see the `header`, so the events will not be bound in this case

Comment: do you mean that the login form must appear once the user clicks login link??

Comment: When you say 'dropdown', you mean that a hidden DIV, namely the DIV with the form element, will appears from the top. is that right?

Comment: @harsh Yes the form will appear only when the user has clicked on it

Comment: @IndieRok Yes it will appear from the top

Comment: @Sushanth the header-login div is wrapped in a <header> div - https://jsfiddle.net/6k9ptg06/2/ updated jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/k6488t60/

Change your css to this

```
#header .header-top-bar .header-login div,
 #header .header-top-bar .header-register div {
  top: 80px;
  display:none;
}

#header .header-top-bar .header-login.active div,
#header .header-top-bar .header-register.active div {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: In the JSfiddle it works, but when I use this CSS in my Apache version it doesn't appear to do anything, it just adds a # at the end of the URL

Comment: Check the code properly again. I don't think the problem is with the server

Comment: the code is exactly the same (I copy and pasted it) I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: what you could do, is get rid of the < a > link and replace it with a simple DIV instead. An hyperlink is meant to take a user to another page or download a file or whatever. Clicking on an hyperlink will produce a page refresh, which adds the # at the end of the url.

Comment: Something I have found, when I change <div class="header-login"> to <div class="header-login active"> it shows the box as I wish. So that rules out any issues with the CSS, I would assume its either the HTML or jQuery